# Android things driver for AR1100

Tags: raspberry-pi, android-things

i try to connect lcd with touch panel AR1100 to Raspberry pi3 with Android things. Android does not have driver for this touch, i found this solve:

create file:

```
/system/usr/idc/Vendor_04d8_Product_0c03.idc
```

and write:

```
# This is an example of an input device configuration file.
# It might be used to describe the characteristics of a built-in touch screen.
# The device is a external device.
device.internal = 0
# The device should behave as a touch screen device.
touch.deviceType = touchScreen
# The device uses the same orientation as the built-in display.
touch.orientationAware = 1
```

But after restart touch not working. What wrong??

How i can connect this touch to android things?

Answer (score 0):

In your Android Things application (not on Android Things system level) you can add AR1100 touch support via Raspberry Pi [UART](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/uart.html) by implementing AR1100 Data Protocol (pp. 14-15 of [datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/AR1100.pdf)):

> The  host  should  be configured for 9600 BAUD, 8 data bits and 1 Stop
> bit.
>
> ...
>
> Touch  reports  always  originate  from  the  AR1100  and are
> transmitted  in  response  to  touch  detection.  The format of the
> touch report is mode-dependent. The  measurement  resolution  for
> touch  coordinates  is 10-bit. The measured values are shifted
> (multiplied by 4)  and  reported  in  a  12-bit  format.  In  the
> reporting protocol,  the  Least  Significant  coordinate  bits  X1:X0
> and Y1:Y0 will be zeros. The resulting full-scale range for reported
> touch coordinates is 0 to 4095.
>
> ...
>
> The  ‘standard’,  5-byte  touch  report  is  formatted  as  in Table 4-2:

etc.

Android Things UART example you can find [here](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-uartloopback).

Comment: @EvgeniySherbak Yes, it's not general solution, but for your app it should works.